Include needed headers in both .c and the corresponding .h or only in the .h?
Assume I have a module filter.c/filter.h.
That module exposes a function in the header:
uint32_t filterStuff(uint32_t input);
This means I need to include stdint.h, and I need it in both the filter.c AND the filter.h
In the past I simply included stdint.h in filter.h. Since filter.h is also included inside filter.c the code has the int32 typedef available as well and everything works.
But when I check that code with clang-tidy I get a

no header providing "uint32_t" is directly included

warning from misc-include-cleaner.
Does this suggest I should include stdint.h in both filter.c AND filter.h separately? Is that considered good style?
NOTE: I'm asking only about the case where something is included in the header directly belonging to some c-file: foo.c and foo.h. I'm not asking about trusting correct indirect includes from headers NOT directly belonging to said module.

You can include a header file as many times as you like – its header guards prevent it from being parsed more than once in a compilation.

You can try telling clang-tidy filter.h and filter.c are associated https://github.com/include-what-you-use/include-what-you-use/blob/master/docs/IWYUPragmas.md#iwyu-pragma-associated - This might silence any warnings for things you'd expect to come from filter.h (assuming it's a file stem issue, that trips the heuristic).

A rule of thumb - include the headers in every file that immediately depends on the stuff declared in that header. That is, if you have a function with uint32_t parameters, then include the stdint.h in both, the h and c files declaring and defining this function.

The header filter.h should include <stdint.h> since one of the functions it declares needs one of the types from <stdint.h>, and a header should be self-contained, minimal and idempotent.  (For more discussion, see Should I use #include in headers? and other questions.)
The code in filter.c necessarily uses filter.h, so it does not really need to include <stdint.h> directly.  However, other source files might use filter.h for some parts of the code but also use types from <stdint.h> separately from the use mandated by filter.h.  It becomes contentious whether those other files should include <stdint.h> directly.  The argument in favour of doing so is that if the code ceases to need filter.h, then the <stdint.h> header will need to be added to the source to provide the now-missing declarations.  The argument against that is "the code will have to be changed when it stops using filter.h, and adding the <stdint.h> header would simply be one of the other necessary changes".
I tend towards the "against" view — I would not include <stdint.h>.  But I'm not 100% consistent about it (is anyone 100% consistent?).  If the policy is to use tools that complain if you don't include the file directly, then follow the rules imposed by that policy and the tools you use.
I still regard self-containment as important.  If I include a header x.h, I should not need to include other headers y.h and z.h (that I may not even be fully cognizant of) in order to use the facilities of x.h.

OK, so basically you say it's a matter of taste/convention. We are currently in the situation that we have to configure which kind of warnings from clang-tidy we want and which warnings should be surpressed. I tend towards your "against" view as well, for the sake of reduced clutter in the c-file, but we will have to agree on something internally. Thanks for the input.

Is there some way to opt-out of this specific behavior in clang-tidy, while keeping checks for e.g. unused includes?
